# Why does this code not end after the break statement?

Tags: python, break

I was wondering why the `break` statement in this code doesn't end it? After `break` it starts the whole code over again, no?

```
u = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']    
while True:
    password = input('Choose a new password. (6 or more of letters and numbers only with at least 1 capitalized): ')
    if len(password) >= 6:
        if password.isalnum():
            for i in password:
                if i in u:
                    print('Thank you, your new password is set up.')
                    break
            else:
                print('letters and numbers only with at least 1 uppercase letter.')
        else:
            print('Only letters or numbers.')
    else:
        print('Thats too short for a password')
```

Comment: that only breaks out of 1 loop, which is the for loop in this case. you're still in the while loop

Comment: As a side note: "Flat is better than nested".  Try to flatten this code, perhaps using functions.

Answer (score 1):

Like [SuperStew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8784938/superstew) said, it is only breaking out of the for loop. Alternatively, you could set the while loop on a variable and edit that instead of the break.

```
notDone = True
while notDone:
    password = input('Choose a new password. (6 or more of letters and numbers only with at least 1 capitalized): ')
    if len(password) >= 6:
        if password.isalnum():
            for i in password:
                if i in u:
                    print('Thank you, your new password is set up.')
                    notDone = False
            else:
                print('letters and numbers only with at least 1 uppercase letter.')
        else:
            print('Only letters or numbers.')
    else:
        print('Thats too short for a password')
```

Comment: Ahh, I will remember that, thank you. I was able to get the result I wanted by importing sys and sys.exit after the valid password message. Is that worse/less manageable than what you did?

Comment: It should be fine. Essentially instead of Python finding it is done, you are just telling it that its done. For maximum performance, do `from sys import exit` and then call `exit()`

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=break#the-break-statement):

> It terminates the nearest enclosing loop

Since the `for` loop is the closest loop, it will terminate. However you are still within the `while` loop, and this hasn't been terminated.

I would instead close the conditions into functions, since this allows you to clarify the purpose of each loop:

1. The `for` to check each character in the password.
2. The `while` to ensure a valid password is set.

```
def check_length(pw):
    if len(pw) >= 6:
        return True
    return False

def contains_uppercase(pw):
    for c in pw:
        if c in "ABC...XYZ":
            return True
    return False

def valid_password(password):
    if check_length(password):
        print('Thats too short for a password')
        return False

    elif password.isalnum():
        print('letters and numbers only with at least 1 uppercase letter.')
        return False

    elif contains_uppercase(password):
        print('Thank you, your new password is set up.')
        return True

    return False

while True:
    password = input('Choose a new password. (6 or more of letters and numbers only with at least 1 capitalized): ')
    if not valid_password(password):
        print('Please try again.')
    else:
        break
```

Comment: I didn't think of that, thank you. I was able to get the result I wanted by importing sys and sys.exit after the valid password message. Is that worse/less manageable than what you did?

Comment: It depends on your usecase. using sys.exit will exit the application. If that's all you need to do then great. If you need to use the password variable you need to _use it_ and not exit the application. :)

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. I was just using this a small test project to help me learn some stuff, Ill never use this haha. Thank you again for the help!